# categoryId region specific

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So right now the "snippet.categoryId" is relative to each country that the video was uploaded in.

Ex:

```
IN (India) video gets id 23 for Comedy
US (United States) gets id 34 for Comedy
```

If I want to group videos by categoryId, it can group videos with different categories on the same id. Is there a way to determine the region the video was uploaded in? Or at least what region the category is specified for?

Answer (score 0):

I check the [video categories for US](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22US%22%7D) and the [video categories for IN](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22IN%22%7D) and for both countries, the `categoryId` for `Comedy` is: `23`.

The issue is that **the "Comedy" category is duplicated** (*by its name*) and with these two `categoryIDs` = `23` and `34`.

Comment: You're totally right. After doing some more processing and reading I noticed that!